# How to pass json payload to Revit DesignAutomation plugin? sample needed

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I want to to pass a json payload to my DA4R plugin but cannot find any example for that. The [CountIt Sample (Beta)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit-samples/count-it/) you posted on your documentation pages is useless without the C# code of the Visual Studio project that goes along...

Answer (score 1):

The input as plain JSON is saved as a file (e.g. `params.json` or any name that you specify on the Activity `localName` argument), so you can pass using (`nodejs`):

```
let payLoad = {
  activityId: ForgeUtils.ACTIVITY_ID,
  arguments: {
    sketchItInput: {
      url: 'data:application/json,'+JSON.stringify(elements)
    },
    onComplete: {
      verb: 'post',
      url: NgrokUtils.getServerUrl() + '/workitemcomplete'
    },
    result: {
      verb: 'put',
      url: signedUrl
    }
  }
};
```

See sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-sketchIt/blob/b372aad96e3035af9364efd4a35c2500df62d15a/server/src/main.js#L119).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, sorry if the question wasn't clear enough... I wanted to see the Revit addin C# code that parses and uses the JSON payload. The examples are of limited use without the C# addin code. I could find on your repo at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-sketchIt/blob/b372aad96e3035af9364efd4a35c2500df62d15a/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/SketchIt.cs. Thanks

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Here is another one: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/master/updateRVTParam/Commands.cs#L33 And check the tutorial at http://learnforge.autodesk.io